# Setting multiple variables to call in a conditional statement

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I want to create an environment variable depending on the location and append that environment variable name to log file. For example, I have multiple AWS accounts and depending on the account I want the variable name to identify that account. I would like to run this in a conditional as well instead I writing multiple scripts.

if account is this echo or printf account and set the account name to that variable before executing the code.

```
aws_bsd='lab'
aws_csd='engineering'
aws_efg='chemistry'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the absolute path of the currently running script using `realpath` and take the decision based on that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

_this_script_path="$(realpath "$0")"  # script path
_this_dir_path="$(dirname "$_this_script_path")"  # scripts' parent directory path

_account_1_path="/home/acc1"
_account_2_path="/home/acc2"

if [[ "$_this_dir_path" == "$_account_1_path" ]]; then
    echo "- setting up account 1"
    # do account 1 specific stuff
    # export VAR1="var1_value"
    # ...
elif [[ "$_this_dir_path" == "$_account_2_path" ]]; then
    echo "- setting up account 2"
    # do account 2 specific stuff
    # ...
fi
```

Note:

I'm not sure whether `realpath` is in POSIX standard, but I find it is widely available. In case you don't have it, there are other methods to do the same `realpath` does. But I believe this is the most concise approach.

Comment: Thanks appreciate this will get me going